# How do I get started with Go?

Tags: go

Basically, the title already says it all: How do I get started with Go? Of course I know the [Go website](http://golang.org/) and the documentation that is there, but what other resources are there?

Any good tutorials, videos, blogs, books, …?

Comment: I'd say look at http://gobyexample.com, one of the best sites that explains the fundamentals of the framework. Also Rob Pike vouched for it on twitter.

Comment: Also check http://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/go/ , the site in general is an amazing mini-reference for almost all languages.

Comment: In addition to reading tutorials, skip setup process and start using the playground: http://play.golang.org/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start with http://tour.golang.org. It will guide you through the language features and differences.

Then install it locally and try to port something simple you've written in another language.

The most important resources are the [standard package docs](http://golang.org/pkg) and sites like http://godoc.org/ which provides an online documentation generator for any public code repositories.

The document [Effective Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html) is also very useful for explanations of how to use the various language features.

There is a collection of videos on [the Go wiki](https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/GoTalks).

For blogs, try http://blog.golang.org/ , http://dave.cheney.net/ , http://labix.org/ and http://www.goinggo.net/ for starters.

Unfortunately, the Go books that are out there are aiming at a moving target so they struggle to be comprehensive. I'd recommend sticking with the official package docs which are usually replete with code examples.

A good tip for *idiomatic* code is to read the [package source files](http://golang.org/src/pkg/), especially the `*_test.go` files as they usually provide nice examples of most of the ways the package *can* be used. This is, as an aside, a wonderful side-effect to comprehensive package tests.

Comment: Also, http://talks.golang.org/. You can almost pick a random one (say, [this](http://talks.golang.org/2013/bestpractices.slide#1) or [this](http://talks.golang.org/2012/10things.slide#1)) and have a good chance of learning something you didn't know.